# Can't install libzeroc-ice3.7

Tags: voip

I've updated and searched for libzeroc-ice3.7, but it isn't found. I'm not sure why. Looking on https://packages.ubuntu.com/ it seems it should be listed for my server.

https://imgur.com/a/p86U9S0.png

Comment: It is [available for 18.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libzeroc-ice3.7). What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: 18.04.1  Sorry, I should have stated those details. It is in the linked screenshot. (Apparently, I can't do images until I have a 10 rep.)

Comment: Not a duplicate, but certainly the answer.  Interesting, because in packages, it appears it was in bionic.

Thanks.